# How can I append associations with uneven elements?

Tags: dataset, associations

My dataset is pretty simple so far:

```
Questions = Dataset[{
<|"Statement" -> "What is the capital of Switzerland?", "Answer" -> "Bern", 
"Incorrect Answers" -> {"Zurich", "Berlin", "Vienna"}|>,
<|"Statement" -> "Who is the king of the jungle?", "Answer" -> "Lion", 
"Incorrect Answers" -> {"Giraffe", "Mouse", "Monkey"}|>,
<|"Statement" -> "2+2?" , "Answer" -> "4", "Incorrect Answers" -> {"15", "13", "1e15"}|>}]
```

[image: Questions]

If I try the following, everything goes right:

```
NewQuestion1 = <|"Statement" -> "To be...", "Answer" -> "or not to be", 
"Incorrect Answers" -> {"or to eat", "continued", "dummy"}|>;
Append[Questions, NewQuestion1]
```

[image: NewQuestions1]

Nevertheless, if I delete the dummy answer of the NewQuestion, it will not work:

```
NewQuestion2 = <|"Statement" -> "To be...", "Answer" -> "or not to be", 
"Incorrect Answers" -> {"or to eat", "continued"}|>;
Append[Questions, NewQuestion2]
```

[image: NewQuestion2]

This issue seems weird since you can declare a data set with uneven lists from the beginning:

```
Questions = Dataset[{
   <|"Statement" -> "What is the capital of Switzerland?", 
    "Answer" -> "Bern", 
    "Incorrect Answers" -> {"Zurich", "Berlin", "Vienna"}|>,
   <|"Statement" -> "Who is the king of the jungle?", 
    "Answer" -> "Lion", 
    "Incorrect Answers" -> {"Giraffe", "Mouse", "Monkey"}|>,
   <|"Statement" -> "2+2?" , "Answer" -> "4", 
    "Incorrect Answers" -> {"15", "13", "1e15"}|>,
   <|"Statement" -> "To be...", "Answer" -> "or not to be", 
    "Incorrect Answers" -> {"or to eat", "continued"}|>
   }]
```

[image: QuestionsUneven]

Any suggestions on how to append NewQuestion2 and/or explanations of why this error is happening?

Comment: I read that question before posting mine and find it different since m_goldberg is trying to append an element of a different class (I must say that I found that quite interesting and certainly something for Mathematica to improve). Here the thing is that I want to append another list.

Comment: `Insert[Questions, NewQuestion2, -1]`. All credits to @m_goldberg in the linked Q&A.

Comment: Super! Not as "elegant" as I am used to in Mathematica, but works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: I voted for this being a duplicate. (Which, as a moderator, takes immediate effect.)  The underlying problem appears to be the same, and the solutions are the same.  Since your problem is resolved I don't see the need to keep this open longer.

Comment: I enquire against since even though the solution is the same, the fact that I explained in the first comment here made it hard to get at the first sight that it could work. Moreover, we talking about undocumented functions and extending the its use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, here is a workaround:

First, we load the package `TypeSystem`:

```
Needs["TypeSystem`"]
```

Now we define the `Dataset` to expect any type:

```
Questions = 
 Dataset[{<|"Statement" -> "What is the capital of Switzerland?", 
    "Answer" -> "Bern", 
    "Incorrect Answers" -> {"Zurich", "Berlin", "Vienna"}|>, <|
    "Statement" -> "Who is the king of the jungle?", 
    "Answer" -> "Lion", 
    "Incorrect Answers" -> {"Giraffe", "Mouse", "Monkey"}|>, <|
    "Statement" -> "2+2?", "Answer" -> "4", 
    "Incorrect Answers" -> {"15", "13", "1e15"}|>}, 
  Vector[Struct[{"Statement", "Answer", "Incorrect Answers"}, {AnyType, AnyType, AnyType}]]]
```

Note the undocumented second argument of `Dataset`

We can now append with no problems:

```
NewQuestion2 = <|"Statement" -> "To be...", "Answer" -> "or not to be", 
   "Incorrect Answers" -> {"or to eat", "continued"}|>;
```

Then

```
Append[Questions, NewQuestion2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Amazing, thanks. Do you also know why this happens? And do you know where does this second argument work? For instance if I used Join to add more columns, could I also specify there that they are AnyType?

Comment: @CarlosChida, I don't know for sure why it happens but think it's a bug. The second argument is undocumented and I don't know the details of its functionality.